# React re-render via setState vs direct DOM manipulation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-manipulation

I have been working with react for about 6 months now and something that always used to bother me is the way re-renders work.

Below is a traditional component that has one input box and sends data to the server to whose value is used by some other forms along with multiple almost static HTML elements that are never used or change very rarely. I am saying very rarely because static elements can be built and stored in a variable in the `componentWillMount()` method. But for this question to be a little more than that, render should contain a call to `buildComplexHTMLFromData` method.

```
buildComplexHTMLFromData = (data) => {
  // Lot of javascript to build the boxes based on the initial or data 
  // that changes so rarely
  // array.map.filter.find etc.
  return (
    <div>
      //Complex HTML element 1
      //Complex HTML element 2
      //....
      //....
      //Complex HTML element n      
    </div>
  )
}

sendDataToBackend = (event) => {
  this.setState(
    { value: event.target.value },
    () => this.functionThatSendsDataToBackend()
  )
}

render() {
  <div>
    // Active input that sends data to the backend
    <input 
      value={this.state.value} 
      onChange={this.sendDataToBackend} 
    />
    {this.buildComplexHTMLFromData()}    
  </div>
}
```

Now setting state upon input box change will trigger even the `buildComplexHTMLFromData` method that does complex javascript all over again. I heard React does something smart by diffing across DOM to efficiently re-render but this javascript is executed anyway.

On the other hand the same functionality can be achieved using two varieties of `sendDataToBackend` method as shown in the snippet below. This however ensures that only the target input element is changed without touching the already rendered elements or executing any javascript on `buildComplexHTMLFromData` method.

```
buildComplexHTMLFromData = (data) => {
  // Lot of javascript to build the boxes based on the initial or data 
  // that changes so rarely
  // array.map.filter.find etc.
  return (
    <div>
      //Complex input box 1
      //Complex input box 2
      //....
      //....
      //Complex input box n      
    </div>
  )
}

sendDataToBackend = (event) => {
  //First strategy
  var element = document.getElementById("persistable-input");
  element && element.value = event.target.value

  //Second strategy
  this.persistableInput.value = event.target.value
}

render() {
  <div>
    // Active input that sends data to the backend or for other forms
    <input 
      id="persistable-input"
      ref={(elem) => { this.persistableInput = elem }}
      value={this.state.value} 
      onChange={this.props.persistedValue} 
    />
    {this.buildComplexHTMLFromData()}    
  </div>
}
```

I don't know if I am missing something or if this is very minimal on performance but I feel it could be quite taxing for complex components. I looked multiple articles on React's reconciliation paradigm but it does not seem to address this.

I would really appreciate if anyone could shed some light into this area of React because I am looking for some cool tips and inputs on performant reconciliation in React in most cases.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn’t React use shadow DOM instead of directly manipulating the DOM?

Comment: Shadow DOM or not, plain DOM manipulation would not re-render all the non-targeted elements right? Only the target element will be modified in the tree.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what the [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) lifecycle hook was created for. If you know that your component shouldn't always re-render, then you can add this lifecycle hook to detect which piece of state is changing. If it something that you don't care about, you can `return false` and the `buildComplexHTMLFromData` function won't ever run.

EDIT:

They also expose a base class called [`PureComponent`](https://60devs.com/pure-component-in-react.html) that handles `shouldComponentUpdate` under the hood for you.

Comment: `shouldComponentUpdate` will decide where the `render()` method has to be called again which here is required to update the value of the input box. However the render method also has the logic to render all other complex HTML elements. Since it's a method the complex javascript is bound to run even if the update is not targeted.

Also `PureComponent` will do a shallow check of all the props nothing fancy either, just decides where to re-execute the render() method.

Comment: Ah, so simple solution. Move your `buildComplexHTMLFromData` into it's own component that only cares about it's props. Then you can move `shouldComponentUpdate` into that component and have it only update for new props.

Comment: Sounds like your component has too many concerns and can be broken down into smaller child components.

Comment: Thank you for the input but I think I already considered doing that but don't you think it's way too much of a component break just to accommodate a single `<input />` box. I have other solutions of just using a `defaultValue` in the input tag which could solve the purpose but I am just wondering on how setState could potentially allow such performance hits.

Comment: It's not overkill at all, it's actually more of a best practice with React. You shouldn't run into the issue you are having with React. If you do, then you are probably doing something wrong. The idea of breaking your UI into the smallest components is what React is all about. Good luck.